# HTML integration

Tags: javascript, html

I have found this gem while browsing this site : http://jsfiddle.net/MX7JC/9/ but I am not able to build a valid HTML who can run the script.

**index.html**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <script src="d3.v2.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="d3portfolio.css" />
            <head>
            <div id="objectives">
                <a href="#agg">Agg</a> 
                <a href="#bal">Bal</a> 
                <a href="#mod">Mod</a> 
                <a href="#inc">Inc</a> 
            </div>
            <div id="d3portfolio"></div>
            <script src="d3portfolio.js"></script>
        </head>
    </html>
```

Everything else is copy/paste from [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MX7JC/9/).

I use aptana studio but even if I upload it to altervista it doesnt work. I only see the "agg" donut chart.

I have 3 other files on my workspace : d3.v2.js, d3portfolio.js and d3portfolio.css

What I am missing ? I try to learn coding on my spare time by trial and errors.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script in the page also makes use of jQuery for the click handler so you need to include that also.

Also use `body` to put your page content not the `head`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>
        <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v2.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="d3portfolio.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="objectives">
            <a href="#agg">Agg</a> 
            <a href="#bal">Bal</a> 
            <a href="#mod">Mod</a> 
            <a href="#inc">Inc</a> 
        </div>
        <div id="d3portfolio"></div>
        <script src="d3portfolio.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

```js
var agg = {
    label: 'Aggressive',
    pct: [30, 10, 6, 30, 14, 10]
  },
  bal = {
    label: 'Balanced',
    pct: [24, 7, 2, 18, 13, 36]
  },
  mod = {
    label: 'Moderate',
    pct: [12, 4, 2, 10, 11, 61]
  },
  inc = {
    label: 'Income',
    pct: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 100]
  },

  data = agg;

var labels = ['LCAP', 'MCAP', 'SCAP', 'Intl', 'Alt', 'Fixed'];

var w = 320, // width and height, natch
  h = 320,
  r = Math.min(w, h) / 2, // arc radius
  dur = 750, // duration, in milliseconds
  color = d3.scale.category10(),
  donut = d3.layout.pie().sort(null),
  arc = d3.svg.arc().innerRadius(r - 70).outerRadius(r - 20);

// ---------------------------------------------------------------------
var svg = d3.select("#d3portfolio").append("svg:svg")
  .attr("width", w).attr("height", h);

var arc_grp = svg.append("svg:g")
  .attr("class", "arcGrp")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + (w / 2) + "," + (h / 2) + ")");

var label_group = svg.append("svg:g")
  .attr("class", "lblGroup")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + (w / 2) + "," + (h / 2) + ")");

// GROUP FOR CENTER TEXT
var center_group = svg.append("svg:g")
  .attr("class", "ctrGroup")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + (w / 2) + "," + (h / 2) + ")");

// CENTER LABEL
var pieLabel = center_group.append("svg:text")
  .attr("dy", ".35em").attr("class", "chartLabel")
  .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
  .text(data.label);

// DRAW ARC PATHS
var arcs = arc_grp.selectAll("path")
  .data(donut(data.pct));
arcs.enter().append("svg:path")
  .attr("stroke", "white")
  .attr("stroke-width", 0.5)
  .attr("fill", function(d, i) {
    return color(i);
  })
  .attr("d", arc)
  .each(function(d) {
    this._current = d
  });

// DRAW SLICE LABELS
var sliceLabel = label_group.selectAll("text")
  .data(donut(data.pct));
sliceLabel.enter().append("svg:text")
  .attr("class", "arcLabel")
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")";
  })
  .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
  .text(function(d, i) {
    return labels[i];
  });

// --------- "PAY NO ATTENTION TO THE MAN BEHIND THE CURTAIN" ---------

// Store the currently-displayed angles in this._current.
// Then, interpolate from this._current to the new angles.
function arcTween(a) {
  var i = d3.interpolate(this._current, a);
  this._current = i(0);
  return function(t) {
    return arc(i(t));
  };
}

// update chart
function updateChart(model) {
  data = eval(model); // which model?

  arcs.data(donut(data.pct)); // recompute angles, rebind data
  arcs.transition().ease("elastic").duration(dur).attrTween("d", arcTween);

  sliceLabel.data(donut(data.pct));
  sliceLabel.transition().ease("elastic").duration(dur)
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")";
    })
    .style("fill-opacity", function(d) {
      return d.value == 0 ? 1e-6 : 1;
    });

  pieLabel.text(data.label);
}

// click handler
$("#objectives a").click(function() {
  updateChart(this.href.slice(this.href.indexOf('#') + 1));
});
```

```css
#d3portfolio {
  width: 320px;
  height: 320px;
}
.chartLabel {
  font: 16px sans-serif;
  fill: #666;
}
.arcLabel {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
  fill: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v2.js"></script>

<div id="objectives">
  <a href="#agg">Agg</a> 
  <a href="#bal">Bal</a> 
  <a href="#mod">Mod</a> 
  <a href="#inc">Inc</a> 
</div>
<div id="d3portfolio"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing you need to do is include the jquery library in your html. Secondly check you head section. You have put the content in it. That is not allowed in html. Move it to the body section.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>
       //Your other scripts and stylesheets 
    </head>
    <body>
        //Your content.
       //You include scripts at the bottom if you like. 
    </body>
</html>
```